# Magento 2.4 Store -> configuration -> Customer -> Customer Configuration not visible in Admin panel

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.4, admin-panel

When I try to create an order in my multiple website magento 2.4 installation, I get this error:
**"A customer with the same email address already exists in an associated website"**

As solution I found that I have to share the customer global in Customer Configuration:
**Store -> Configuration -> Customer -> Customer Configuration**

[image]

My problem is, that Customer Configuration does not exist in my Admin Panel.

Thanks for help
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly**, make sure your admin user has the **Customers Section** resource or all **Roles resources**.

You can check it by going to System > Permissions > User Roles. Open the role your admin user is assigned to, switch to the Role Resources tab, search for "Customers Section" and make sure it is checked.

**If your admin user already has that resource**, run this command from your Magento root directory to find which files declares/reference to the **Customer Configuration** section config (it has section ID `customer`):
`grep -r --include system.xml "<section id=\\\"customer\\\" " app vendor`

It will return a list of files with configuration for the `customer` section, eg:

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/adminhtml/system.xml:        <section id="customer" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
```

- If you see any records that contain `showInDefault="0"` or `showInWebsite="0"` `showInStore="0"`, you should edit that file to change those values from **0** to **1**.
  Clear the **Configuration** cache to see the result.
- If you don't see any records that contain `showInDefault="0"` or `showInWebsite="0"` `showInStore="0"` but you see other records except the once from `vendor/magento/module-customer`, you should try to check modules that contain these files.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's the result:
app/code/Lof/ForceCustomerLogin/etc/adminhtml/system.xml:        <section id="customer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
app/code/Lof/CustomerSegment/etc/adminhtml/system.xml:        <section id="customer" translate="label">
vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/adminhtml/system.xml:        <section id="customer" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

All is set = 1

Comment: All configs look good. Are you sure your admin user has all Roles resources or at least has the **Customers Section** resource? You can check it by going to System > Permissions > User Roles. Open the role your admin user is assigned to, switch to the Role Resources tab, search for "Customer**s** Section" and make sure it is checked.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me to find out the problem. Maybe you can help with an other??? In your profile you write that you are available for hire? Thats right? If yes, how much you charge?

Comment: Glad to hear that. Sure, I can help, but it is worth saying that I'm not sure can give you the solution **soon** if your problem takes time. You also can consider my paid support service for quick support. Here is my profile with a summary about myself https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/39884/tu-van?tab=profile

Comment: I sent you an email. Please check and let me know about the costs, for example hiring full-time. A personal question: Where are you living?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140833/discussion-between-dr-christian-kusche-and-tu-van).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I have installed some extensions from LandOfCoder. Two of these extensions are
Lof_CustomerSegment
Lof_ForceCustomerLogin
After I have disabled these extensions in app/ect/config.php the default customer configuration is visible again.

Thanks for the help